# How do I create a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm am trying to create a stored procedure that generates the update statements to update incorrectly entered SSN with the correct SSN in over 193 tables with SSN columns one whole transaction. I want this stored procedure to log the error messages and rollback the enter transaction in cases where the update fails.

How do I approach this?

My approach to this exercise is as listed below: if there is an efficient way of doing this, please let me know. I need quality check done on my code. Please help!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspUpdateSSNErrorLog
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    CREATE TABLE #UpdateSSNErrorLog
    (
      [ErrorID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      [ErrorNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
      [ErrorDescription] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
      [ErrorProcedure] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
      [ErrorState] [int] NULL,
      [ErrorSeverity] [int] NULL,
      [ErrorLine] [int] NULL,
      [ErrorTime] [datetime] NULL    
    );

    INSERT INTO #UpdateSSNErrorLog  
    (
         ErrorNumber 
        ,ErrorDescription 
        ,ErrorProcedure 
        ,ErrorState 
        ,ErrorSeverity 
        ,ErrorLine 
        ,ErrorTime 
    )
    VALUES
    (
         ERROR_NUMBER()
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE()
        ,ERROR_STATE()
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY()
        ,ERROR_LINE()
        ,GETDATE()  
    );

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;  
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE uspUpdateSSN
    AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @OldSSN VARCHAR(9);
DECLARE @NewSSN VARCHAR(9);
DECLARE @CMD   VARCHAR( 400);

-- Create the table.
CREATE TABLE #updateSSNlist (
    Updatelist varchar(400)
);

INSERT INTO #updateSSNlist
SELECT 
'UPDATE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] SET [' + Column_Name + ']=@NewSSN    WHERE [' + Column_Name + ']=@OldSSN;'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE Column_Name ='SSN';

-- Declare a cursor.

DECLARE SSN_Update CURSOR FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM #updateSSNlist

OPEN SSN_Update;

FETCH NEXT
FROM SSN_Update
INTO @CMD;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC @CMD;
FETCH NEXT
FROM SSN_Update
INTO @CMD;
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    EXEC uspUpdateSSNErrorLog --To log update errors
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH

CLOSE SSN_Update;
DEALLOCATE SSN_Update;

DROP TABLE  #UpdateSSNErrorLog;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a physical table first off with the table name so you know which table it errored out on. Second, I think you should execute all your updates at once. **Note:** I don't know if your SSN column is INT or VARCHAR. If Varchar, you'll need to add quotes around it.

Try this out:

```
CREATE TABLE UpdateSSNErrorLog
(
    [ErrorID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [TableName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [ErrorNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ErrorDescription] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [ErrorProcedure] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ErrorState] [int] NULL,
    [ErrorSeverity] [int] NULL,
    [ErrorLine] [int] NULL,
    [ErrorTime] [datetime] NULL    
);


DECLARE @OldSSN VARCHAR(9) = 1;
DECLARE @NewSSN VARCHAR(9) = 2;
DECLARE @CMD   VARCHAR(MAX);

 SELECT @cmd =  COALESCE(@cmd,'') +
'BEGIN TRY 
 BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] SET [' + Column_Name + '] = ' + @NewSSN + '  
    WHERE [' + Column_Name + '] = ' + @OldSSN + '
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO UpdateSSNErrorLog  
(
     TableName
    ,ErrorNumber 
    ,ErrorDescription 
    ,ErrorProcedure 
    ,ErrorState 
    ,ErrorSeverity 
    ,ErrorLine 
    ,ErrorTime 
)
VALUES
(   ''' + Table_name  + '''
    ,ERROR_NUMBER()
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE()
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE()
    ,ERROR_STATE()
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY()
    ,ERROR_LINE()
    ,GETDATE()  
);
END CATCH '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME != 'UpdateSSNErrorLog'
        --AND Column_Name ='SSN';

SELECT @cmd

----To Execute
--EXEC(@cmd)
```

Also you could add a column to Update SSNErroLog to note whether you resolved an error or not or you could simply delete the rows once resolved.

Comment: the code must rollback all transaction if one of the update statement fails. Can you incorporate that into your?